# Arcgis table and Excel sheet dynamic linking

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, excel

How i can link an ArcGIS table with Excel sheet, so the table updated automatically when i update the excel sheet?

Also, can i have sub-table in ArcGIS?

Comment: I don't think that you can (I'm really curious on how if I'm wrong!) have a dynamic link to an excel sheet. However, if you use Access databases (.mdb) for storing your feature classes, you can also edit their attribute tables i Access. Editing outside of Arcmap is risky, though.

Comment: Please ask only one question per Question (you'll need to define "sub-table" as well).

Comment: Have you tried doing exactly what you've asked? ArcGIS is capable of reading Excel spreadsheets as tables, and you can link them to other tables/featureclasses if you have appropriate keys..

Answer (score 3):

You will not be able to edit a worksheet via ArcMap, they are read only. You can find out all about Excel worksheets and their limitations on the page [Understanding how to use Microsoft Excel files in ArcGIS](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000001w000000).

You need to export your data out of Excel: into a dBase, personal or file geodatabase table. I personally prefer using personal geodatabases as you can ODBC into these from other applications.

Comment: i'm talking about editing excel via Arcgis, i will update the excel outside arcgis, and i want the arcgis table to be updated automatically.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, this link might be promising: http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0104/files/excel.pdf

This blog claims that it is possible in 3 steps: "First, create an Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) data source in Windows, then reformat 
the data in Excel, and finally connect to the Excel file in ArcCatalog." This would create a live link, and each time you updated the data in excel, those changes would be reflected in Arc.

Personally, I would prefer to keep the two things separate and just join the data as necessary...

Answer (score 1):

Answering the 2nd question here (although I would recommend putting it in a stand-alone question) "Also, can i have sub-table in ArcGIS?"

It sounds like you are interested in creating a relationship class, where in you would have 1 main table, then 1 or many secondary tables. For example, one table with names of property owners (Bill, John, Allison). And another table showing the contact info for those owners using the names as a primary key (Bill- 123 Main St, John- 321 Walker Ave....)

If this is what you are looking for, check out this link: http://blogs.esri.com/esri/esritrainingmatters/2009/02/26/relates-vs-relationship-classes/

Your data will need to be in a file geodatabase, and I would recommend setting the whole thing up in ArcCatalog.